# Getting a null in my list component variable. Cannot read properties of null (reading 'date')

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I have a list card component which displays devices in a list with their name, brand, image, bookedUntil(for how long is it booked if it's booked). All of this information is coming from a Json file. I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way of doing the *if(!bookedUntil) { ... }* part ? Because I tried doing it with ternary operators inside the *return( )* but I couldn't get it to display both of the  and the text if it's booked or not. So I resorted to displaying it with different variables.
2. I keep getting an error that the date is null and I can't display it even in the console. Tried a different if statement but I still kept getting the same error. The main thing I tried to accomplish is that the cycle would get information about the item is it not booked (checks if bookedUntil is null, if it's null, then displays *AvailableItemIcon* with text "Available".) and if it's booked (else if bookedUntil is not null there are dates with how long each device is booked for. So if there are X dates and X amount of devices it would display *BookedItemIcon* text "booked until" and one of the earliest dates out of X dates, because all of the devices are boooked).

**ListCard component:**

```
const ReservationsListCard = ({
  device: { id, name, brand, bookedUntil, quantity, image },
  liked = false,
}) => {
  let stateIcon;
  let stateText;
  var min = null;

  let dateArray = [];

  if (!bookedUntil) {
    stateIcon = <AvailableItemIcon />;
    stateText = "Available";
  } else {
    stateIcon = <BookedItemIcon />;
    stateText = "Booked until";

    dateArray = bookedUntil;

    for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
      var current = dateArray[i];
      if (min != null || current.date < min.date) {
        min = current;
      } 
    }
  }

  return (
    <a href={"/device/" + id} className="reservations-list-card">
      <img className="reservations-list-card__image" alt="device" src={image} />
      <div className="reservations-list-card__brand ">{brand}</div>
      <div className="reservations-list-card__name">{name}</div>
      <div className="reservations-list-card__availability">
        {stateIcon} &nbsp;&nbsp;
        {stateText}
        {console.log(min.date)}
      </div>
      <div className="reservations-list-card__quantity">
        QUANTITY: {quantity}
      </div>
    </a>
  );
};

ReservationsListCard.propTypes = {
  device: PropTypes.object,
};

export default ReservationsListCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if (!bookedUntil)` will never run and will always go to the `else` block. Empty arrays are also "true".

When the `bookedUntil` array is empty, and you assign its first value to `current` you get `undefined`. Later when checking `current.date`, you basically check `undefined.date` which throws an error.

You need to check the array's length:

```js
if (!bookedUntil.length) {
  // ... rest of the code
}
```